# Is there a way to get update time stamp of given record attribute in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing few records, which are often being updated. There is no field, like `"UpdateTimeStamp"` and i have no possibility to create it. Is there any `SQL Server` function (or some other way) to get the last update time, but for a certain attribute (`column`), not the whole record? Thanks for any help

Comment: `timestamp` (a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`) doesn't store the time a row was last effected either; it's just a `binary` value that changes every time the row does. If *you* don't store information on when a row/column was last updated, then that data doesn't exist.

Comment: And even if the table somehow tracked updates, there is certainly no buit-in functionality to track updates of a column alone -- to the engine, an update is an update of a row. Having a specific track record of when a column changed requires things like temporal tables and/or custom triggers. If it isn't possible to add any columns, though, making the table temporal isn't an option either.

Comment: You think the database system should incur the overhead of tracking a last update time for every individual column in every individual row, just on the off chance that someone *might* want that information? Surprisingly, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server offers a feature called [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) that can do what you need. However, it is not turned on by default, and it requires significant additional server resources, since you're effectively doubling the server workload and perpetually storing all your transactional history.